# Why did Hela need Heimdal's sword?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor:Ragnarok*, Hela spends a large portion of the movie (off-screen) searching for Heimdal, so she can use his sword Hofund to open the Bifrost.

But we saw in the original *Thor* movie that Odin's staff can also open the Bifrost; Loki uses it to bring Laufey to Asgard. Hela got the staff pretty soon after getting to Asgard, so why didn't she use it to activate the Bifrost?

Comment: Going by the enchantment on Mjolnir it seems plausible that Hela simply might not have been able to access the full powers of the spear. Given that both Thor and Hela ignore the spear after a certain point in their fight it's evident that neither of them saw a lot of value in it.

In addition, Hela has been exiled for a long time. She might not even know there's alternates to the sword.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know: You should leave that as an answer rather than as a comment (and ideally support your speculation with citations).

Answer (score 14):

Although it's possible that Gungnir is somehow drained of its Odinforce powers by the death of Odin (noting that neither Thor nor Hela act like it's anything more than a big pointy stick when they fight) the most obvious explanation is that she's either ***unable to use it in the same way, perhaps because her own powers work differently to his*** or ***that she's simply unaware that it can be used to power the Bifrost, having been out of the loop for x thousand years.***

The latter is borne out by her statement, seemingly definitive, on the subject.

> **HELA (CONT'D):** *That sword is the key to opening the Bi-Frost.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Thor: Ragnarok - Script.](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor-Ragnarok.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Also possible that gungnir only worked with the first bifrost that Thor destroyed

Comment: @Antheloth - I thought about that. Also, that knowing that Hela might be coming back, Odin might have put some anti-Hela protection on the Bifrost and/or that Heimdall put some an additional lock on the Bifrost to stop Gungnir from being used after Hela invaded. The possibilities are endless, but I think my answer covers the most obvious ones.